# Different Mounts per User

Tags: linux, mount

Is there a way that I could create a Linux-based system where each user has different mount points?

For example you could have the "real" filesystem like this that root uses:

```
/dev/sda1 mounted to /
/bin
/home/uuid1
/home/uuid2
/home/uuid3
```

Then user1 with the uuid1 could see something this:

```
/home/uuid1 mounted to /
/bin mounted to /bin
```

Then user2 could be the same but with uuid2, etc..

I think having a system setup like this could be used to manage dependencies and sandbox user data completely, preventing users from even seeing that there are directories they can not access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [mount namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html), configure your system so that every user is given a particular mount namespace when he/she logs in.

So you don't need a full-blown container for that (though if you find a container easier to use, by all means use a container). A container will basically make use of mount namespaces and the other namespaces.

Comment: While the containers provide a more complete sandbox, this is more applicable to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are containers:

- manage dependencies
- sandbox (user) data completely

You would do this by creating a container for each user (which includes the mountpoints), then inside this container create the user.